# Renderflex overflowed error, also when i wrap column with SingleChildScrollView or ListView my UI disappered

Tags: flutter

I am creating a Login page, when i click on text field due to overlapping keyboard i got error......................................................................................................
**Renderflex overflowed error, also when i wrap column with SingleChildScrollView or ListView my UI disappered. new to flutter lagging in concept , plz help.**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_chat_application_1/modals/customtheme.dart';
import 'package:flutter_chat_application_1/widgets/customappbar.dart';
import 'package:flutter_chat_application_1/widgets/widget.dart';

class SignIn extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignIn({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SignInState createState() => _SignInState();
}

class _SignInState extends State<SignIn> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: CustomAppBar(),
        body: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Spacer(),
                Form(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      TextFormField(
                          style: myTextStyle(),
                          decoration: textFieldInputDecoration('email')),
                      TextFormField(
                        style: myTextStyle(),
                        decoration: textFieldInputDecoration('password'),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 16,
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                        padding:
                            EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 8),
                        child: TextButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          child: Text(
                            'Forgot Password?',
                            style: myTextStyle(),
                          ),
                        ))
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 16,
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {},
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                        gradient: LinearGradient(
                            colors: [Color(0xff007EF4), Color(0xff2A75BC)])),
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    child: Text(
                      'Sign In',
                      style: biggerTextStyle(),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 16,
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {},
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                    child: Text(
                      'Sign in with Google',
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontSize: 17, color: CustomTheme.textColor),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 16,
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Don\'t have account?',
                      style: myTextStyle(),
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: Text('Register Now',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 16,
                            )))
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                )
              ],
            )));
  }
}
```

Comment: Your TextFormFields should be wrapped with Expanded. Your column has no height limit so you're being cautioned that your column children expands into infinity. This question has been asked many times on stackoverflow though...

Comment: yeah i see many of them and then trying wrapping my column with SingleChildScrollView, but let me try your solution.

Comment: yeah, single child view is not matching with container there are more errors coming out with this.